# Download URL for HEAD revision of a file in VisualSVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

With VisualSVN server, you can get a direct download link like this:

http://myserver/!svn/ver/15/file.txt

by navigating to the page for a speicfic file and clicking download.

Is there a simple url to get the HEAD revision of the same file?